# How does the latest version of Derby Apache work?

Tags: derby

I want to create tables in eclipse using Derby Apache Version 10.15.1.3. I installed it and extracted the file. But i dont't understand how to setup the envoirment and make eclipse able to create tables using queries. Do I need a
extra tool for that?

Comment: Take a look here: https://www.eclipse.org/datatools/project_connectivity/connectivity_doc/Connect%20to%20Derby%20using%20DTP%20M2.htm

Comment: If you're completely new to Apache Derby, consider working your way through the Derby tutorial: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.15/getstart/index.html